# Plot every nth row from np.load.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have written the following python code to read data from a txt file and plot every 100th row of the data. However, my code is not working as i intend it to i.e. All the rows are plotted.

My data has 4 columns and about 150 000 rows

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

input_filename = input('Enter the input filename: ')
x,y,z,a = np.loadtxt(input_filename, unpack=True, delimiter=',')
plt.grid()
a = [::100]
z = [::100]
plt.scatter(a, z, s=0.1, c='blue', alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of the data?

Comment: code as shown will produce a syntax error.

Comment: @Simon My data has 4 columns and about 150000 rows.

Comment: `a = [::100]` is not valid python. You may want to index `a`, `b = a[::100]; q = z[::100]; plt.scatter(b,q)`.

Comment: `a=a[::100]` and `z=z[::100]` should do it

Comment: a=a[::100] and z=z[::100] works perfectly! Thank you very much!